# What do modern day cryptographers work on?

Tags: soft-question, cryptography

I am a student of Pure Mathematics.I want to get some information on the following:

$1$.What do modern day cryptographers work on?

$2$. How does pure mathematics influence modern day cryptography?

$3$. What are some open problems in modern Cryptography and how does mathematics affect them?

Comment: Please do not close the question; I need some help

Comment: Why exactly do you need help?

Comment: Because I need some motivation for a course in Cryptography @vadim123

Comment: How about the joy of learning, or the desire to get a good grade, or the possibility of getting a job using what you learn in the course?

Comment: none seem to work unless I get the answer of what are its applications @vadim123

Comment: Are you quite sure you don't have an assignment in which you need to research the above three topics?

Answer (score 1):

Regarding 1 or 3:

E.g. [Homomorphic encryption](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homomorphic_encryption) has been mentioned as "Holy grail of Cryptography".

It would allow to provide encrypted inputs to some service provider,
who would be able to perform useful calculations on the inputs, without him knowing the decrypted form.

Kind of putting some ingredients into a locked box, giving it to the provider who shakes and bakes it, and when you open the returned box, you get some nice pizza.

Comment: @anon Thanks, I got it, after some minutes. :-)